# ECS: Generate 2 Task Definitions from a single Docker Compose File

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have an architecture represented in this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  flask:
    container_name: flask
    image: "user/demo_flask"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: "user/demo_mysql"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Here the `flask` service is a Flask app connecting to the `mysql` DB, which is just `mysql:5.7` with some custom configuration. I need the services to communicate (in particular, `flask` has to be able to reach `mysql`).
I want to deploy such an architecture to ECS using EC2 Launch Type. I plan to use `ecs-cli` to generate the Task Definitions. As long as I can understand, if I include in my directory the file `ecs-params.yml` :

```
version: 1
task_definition:
  services:
    flask:
      cpu_shares: 50
      mem_limit: 262144000
    mysql:
      cpu_shares: 50
      mem_limit: 262144000
```

I get a single Task Definition, which is not what I want. I would like two separate Task Definitions, each one with a single container. Is it possible to get this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One service can not be run with two task definition in ECS Cluster.
What you can do here is to create two task definition (one for flask and another for mysql) and create two service using these two task definition.Now you can make communication using service discovery in ECS Cluster. Please check this aws service discovery [document](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok for going with two separate Services. Take into account that I need to use EC2 Launch Type. I am trying to follow the indications in [the linked document](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/), still they're not satisfactory. I SSH into a Container Instance, I connect to a running container using `docker exec`, but still the Route53 records (like `mysql.local`) are not properly working... Any guess why?

Comment: sorry,its really hard to quess without knowing the details. but keep trying